# Trouble of viewing an XML file encoded in utf-8 with non-ascii characters

Tags: java, character-encoding, clob

I have an xml file which gets its data from an oracle table of CLOB type. I wrote into the Clob value using Unicode Stream

```
Writer value = clob.setCharacterStream(0L);
value.write(StrValue));
```

When I write non-ascii characters like chinese and then access the clob attribute using PL/SQL developer, I see the characters showing up as they are. However, when I put the value in an xml file encoded in UTF-8 and try to open the xml file through IE, i get the error message

> "an invalid character was found in text content. Error processing
>   resource ...".

The other interesting thing is that when I write into CLOB using ascii stream, like:

```
OutputStream value = clob.getAsciiOutputStream();
value.write(strValue.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

then, the characters appear correctly in the XML on browser , but are messy in DB when accessed using PL/SQL developer.

Is there any problem in converting unicode characters to UTF-8. Any suggestion please?